# Can I use brython to develope Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, brython

First, thank you for all your help, since this question has bothered me for a few days. I am not a native speaker of English, so if I make some grammar mistakes or describe the questions unclearly, please forgive me. :)

Originally, I was a crawler only using Python. However, my company wants me to develop a tool which can help them to gain the specific information on the website.

So maybe I should describe the tool first, so you guys will know why I want to use Brython.

1. The user will open the website containing the information they want to catch.
2. They just click a button and the information will be sent directly to a Outlook file.

As you see, Chrome extensions would be a best choice for the first step, so I am going to develop the Chrome extension. However, the main problem is that I am not so familiar with JavaScript, HTML and CSS, so I want to develop extensions with Brython. Unfortunately, I have tried for a few days, but I still cannot execute the extension programmed by me in Brython to get the whole website's information, which means I even cannot finish the first step.

So I think I should come here to find out whether Brython can help me achieve this goal or not. Please give me a favor! I am free to use other methods or programming languages to achieve the goal. If you have any suggestion, feel free to tell me.

Deeply thank you all. :)

Comment: The description is not very... descriptive. The user opens a webpage and with a button you want to download the whole webpage, a part of the webpage,...?

Answer (score 0):

As jonathanverner [said](https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/issues/593#issuecomment-355861846) on GitHub:

> Actually, using Brython in an extension is completely doable. As a
>   proof of concept, I hacked together a very crude extension which adds
>   a "Python console" to the Browser Dev Tools. It isn't very useful, at
>   the moment, but you can look at it to help you write your extension.